# how do I predict values for specific input based on R_D curve in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression

I have two arrays named `PSNR` and `bitrate`. They have the same size 100x6 and each of these cells in two arrays is corresponding to this (psnr, bitrate). for each bitrate, we have the related PSNR value. each row is an R-D curve. The value of the first column in the bitrate array can have values between 800k-1500k for the second column the value is between 1500k-2500k and so on till column 6 when the values are between 5500k-6500k. now I need to change the value to for example 1000k for the first column to 6000k for column six. but I need to change the related value in the PSNR array too. how can I do this? do I need to have a regression function? or do I have to fit a function on this R-D curve and then predict the PSNR value for the wanted bitrate?
[image]

[image]

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: for example, in the above images, we know for Bitrate 660256 (0,0) the PSNR value is 38.4793 (0,0). I need to know if the bitrate was 1000000, what will be the value of PSNR. I have to do this for all values in column 1. for values in column 2, I have to know the PSNR value if the bitrate was 2000000 and so on.

Comment: now my question is what is the solution? do I need to use curve fitting? or there is another solution

Comment: You ask "to change the related value in the PSNR array too. how can I do this? do I need to have a regression function? or do I have to fit a function on this R-D curve and then predict the PSNR value for the wanted bitrate"  This is a signals processing/math question not a programming question